# not able to display the list values in my custom arraylist implementation

Tags: java

My list impl:

```
public class TestMyList implements List{
     int index=0;
     int size;
     Object [] element;
     public TestMyList(){
     element=new Object[10];
  }

  @Override
  public boolean add(Object ele) {
    element[index++]=ele;
    size=index;
    return true;
  }

}
```

class which implements my custom list:

```
public class TestClass   {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    TestMyList list=new TestMyList();
    list.add("hello");
    list.add("i am here");
    System.out.println(list.size());


    System.out.println(list);

  }

}
```

when i run the above program, it displays mypack.TestMyList@2c84d9, instead of [hello, i am here]

please help me in resolving this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 System.out.println(list);
```

When you call `System.out.println`, That apparently calls the `toString()` method of your `list` Object. Since you didn't ovveride `toString()`, it calls the default implementation. Ovveride `toString()` method to print as you wish.

To implement just look at the source code of ArrayList and see how toString() ovverriden.

Comment: thanks for your response...